# Write information from a lookup file into another file

Tags: bash, shell, file

There is a directory of files that have the following content:

doc1.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>
```

doc2.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38>
```

Also, there is a lookup file vocab.tsv which contains class names with respect to the numeric coding:

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38>        Pharmakologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43>        Medizinische Mikrobiologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56>        Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht
```

(The delimiter is supposed to be a tab but can be undefined.)

How can the files above be extended with their respective class names?

The result should look like this:

doc1.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56>        Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie
```

doc2.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43>        Medizinische Mikrobiologie 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38>        Pharmakologie
```

The inelegant approach so far:

```
for tsv in *.tsv ; do

    while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
        
        newLine=$(grep "${LINE}" vocab.tsv)

        sed -i 's/${LINE}/$newLine/g' $tsv
    done < $tsv

done
```

but the result is utter nonsense:

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43> > 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28> > 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38> > 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38>
```

For starters: The grep command, which works perfectly on the bash, cuts the class names when run in the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "\t" 'FNR==NR{ urls[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print $1"\t"urls[$1] }' lookupfile doc1.tsv
```

Using awk and tab as the field delimiter, run through the lookupfile first (FNR==NR) Create an array called urls with the url as the index and name as the value. Then run through the second file. Print the first tab delimited field as well as the value in the corresponding urls array entry.

Comment: Not sure, I use it correctly, but the output is identical to doc1.tsv instead of appending the class names.

Comment: Make sure the files are properly tab separated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lookup file is out of scope. How could the delimiter be replaced automatically to make sure?

Comment: The -F flag dictates the delimiter to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution is dependant on all the files having the same field delimiter (assumed to be tab from you question about tsv files) It's also dependant on the separators being known in advance. The default separator with no -F is specified is a space. Problem is that some of the class names have spaces i.e. Medizinische Mikrobiologie and  only the  Medizinische part will be picked up as the name

Comment: It works when the field separator is not specified: awk 'FNR==NR{ urls[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print $1"\t"urls[$1] }' lookupfile doc1.tsv

Thank you for the main idea!

Comment: It you have managed to get it to work, that's great. If you could access the answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is given by [Raman Sailopal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7840440/raman-sailopal)

`awk 'FNR==NR{ urls[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print $1"\t"urls[$1] }' vocab.tsv oc1.tsv`

In order to do this for all files in the directory:

```
for tsv in *.tsv ; do

    tsv2=${tsv%.tsv}.tsv2

    awk 'FNR==NR{ urls[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print $1"\t"urls[$1] }' vocab.tsv $tsv >> $tsv2

done
```

Of course, it would be more elegant without segwaying to .tsv2.