# awk: How to get the whole string from a lookup file

Tags: shell, awk

This question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848448/write-information-from-a-lookup-file-into-another-file):

There are many tsv files containing classification elements like this:

doc1.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56> 
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>
```

There is also a lookup table that additionally contains the classnames:

lookup.tsv

```
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.38>        Pharmakologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/44.43>        Medizinische Mikrobiologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56>        Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht
```

[Raman Sailopal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7840440/raman-sailopal) already gave a very good hint on the solution which is the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ urls[$1]=$2 } FNR!=NR { print $1"\t"urls[$1] }' lookup.tsv doc1.tsv >> result.tsv
```

Unfortunately, the command just gets the first string up to a blank, but as in "Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht" the whole text is required. What has to be added?

Comment: doesn't tsv stands for ```TabSepratedValues```. Your ```lookup.tsv ``` is actually ```SSV ``` (SpaceSeparatedValues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `$0` instead of `$2` in the loopup table, as it seems like you want to print the whole line

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { urls[$1]=$0 } FNR!=NR { print urls[$1] }' lookup.tsv doc1.tsv
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56>        Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With yoru shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/<.*> +/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",val)
}
(val in arr)
' doc1 lookup
```

***2nd solution:*** To get only value apart from URL from doc2 Input_file try following, 1st solution will give complete line.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/<.*> +/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",val)
}
(val in arr){
  print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' doc1 lookup
```

Comment: Its late night here, will add detailed explanation in few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `grep -f`:

```
$ grep -Fwf doc1.tsv lookup.tsv
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/58.28>        Pharmazeutische Technologie
<http://uri.gbv.de/terminology/bk/86.56>        Gesundheitsrecht. Lebensmittelrecht
```

Note that even though `-w` is used then the lines from `doc1.tsv` will be matched against the whole line in `lookup.tsv` and not the first column